# How to build glib library with specific gcc version

Tags: gcc, glib

On my system default gcc version is 4.4.7 , But i want to build glib library with gcc 6.3 version.
For that i tried running ./configure from glib source as shown below:

```
../configure  CC="/version/global/pkgs/gcc/v6.3.0/bin/gcc" CFLAGS='-fPIC' CXXFLAGS='-fPIC' --enable-static=yes --prefix=/home/kallel/glib_63/glib-2.56.1/new_glib63 --enable-libmount=no --with-pcre=/home/kallel/pcre_lib/pcre-8.20/pcre_library
```

Once after building glib library. To see on which  gcc compiler version it got built with following command:-

```
strings -a libglib-2.0.so.0.5600.1 | grep "GCC: ("
o/p:-
 GCC: (GNU) 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-9)
 GCC: (Synopsis) 6.3.0
 GCC: (GNU) 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-4)
```

I could not understand why it is still showing output with 4.4.7, Please help me in understanding the output. Is there anything wrong in my ./configure command? How do we make sure that library was built with gcc 6.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I could not understand why it is still showing output with 4.4.7

Your library contains object code that you built, *as well as* parts of GLIBC that are required to support shared libraries (`crti.o`, `crtn.o`, etc.).

These parts will continue to show whatever GCC they were built with, regardless of what you build `glib` code with.

Comment: But the original library i.e glib is compiled with gcc 6.3 right ?

Comment: @santosh Yes, it is.